# How to import Group price in magento through csv?

Tags: magento, import

I need to **import wholesale price and retail price** both for each products in my website

so I tried to create test product with group price and export that.

and with those fields tried to import, I tried that using both "import" and "dataflow/import", in all case I am getting import successful message , but actually not imported that group prices

[image: csv format for update prices]

Answer (score 2):

By default Magento Import doesn't support for this. 
You can either use the custom code as:

```
// add a pricing to store 1
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(1)->load(1234);
$product->setData('group_price',array (
    array (
        "website_id" => 1,
        "cust_group" => 2,
        "price" => 105
    )));
$product->save();
```